# Android : java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: U_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ERROR /$

Tags: java, android, regex, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have got

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: U_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ERROR /$

exception in crash log of my app in production.

What may be causing it?

It doesn't seem like OOM, as crash log shows

```
VM free: 2.5MB
VM total: 48.24MB
VM max.: 512MB
RAM: 2.77GB
```

Here is the culprit line of code

`myString = myString.replaceAll("/$","");`

Comment: Try: `myString = myString.replaceFirst("/$", "");` as `replaceAll` is not really needed. But most likely error is somewhere else.

Comment: If you just need to remove a `/` from the end of the string, you do not need a regex. Just check if a string `endsWith` a `/` and if yes, use a `substring` to get the part of the string from the beginning till the last but one char.

Comment: I wonder if the same error will happen with `myString.replaceFirst("(?s)(.*)/$","$1")`

Comment: @anubhava

I understand that what I am doing it  not the best way. I will improve it. I would like to know, however what is causing the exception.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can't reproduce it, as it is from device in production. Do you have any ideas as to what may be causing the exception?

Comment: @q126y: The engine itself given a specific input. The regex you use is not optimal: it has to find each `/` and then check for the end of string position. If the input is huge, it may get stuck. So, what I suggest is: 1) if the texts are huge, discard the regex completely, 2) try grabbing the whole string with `.*`, and let it backtrack 1-2 times to check for the `/` at the end.

Comment: @q126y Did you find any root cause for this?

Comment: Have you found the culprit? We occasionally get the same exception for Pattern.compile("HTTP/.+? ((4\\d\\d)|(5\\d\\d)) .+?$", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE)